# how to make the Pycparser to understand my c function

Tags: python-2.7, pycparser

I am using the pycparser for parsing my C code. When I run the script, pycparser could not understand the function and it throws an error like below.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\__init__.py", line 93, in parse_file
return parser.parse(text, filename)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 124, in parse
return self.cparser.parse(text, lexer=self.clex, debug=debuglevel)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 265, in parse
return self.parseopt_notrack(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 1047, in parseopt_notrack
  tok = self.errorfunc(errtoken)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 1423, in p_error
  column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 54, in _parse_error
  raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
ParseError: dsc.c:2592:1: before: {
```

The line number it shows is nothing but an function like this

```
void dsc (void)
{
```

Can anyone tell how to make the pycparser to undertand my function?

```
 static void dsc (void)
 {
 UINT8 j, i;
 static UINT16 jump;
 for (j = 0; j< 10; j++)
 {
 jump = dsc_jump

 for
  (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
 if
 (
 ((jump & 0x50 != 0)
  )
 {
 jump  = dsc_jump
  }
  }

  }
```

Comment: It might help to show your whole function so we can reproduce your error. Ie, post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid C code? Because it's not. Are you sure you copied the code correctly here? As part of an SSCCE (not sure if you read the link or not), you have to also give us the _exact_ commands we need to use in order to reproduce your error, including the _exact_ code.

Answer (score 2):

Your function isn't valid C code. I always suggest to run pycparser only on code that you know compiles. pycparser's error messages are not as good as Clang's or gcc's, so it's harder to figure out where the error is. If I compile your function with gcc, for example, I get:

```
static void dsc (void)
 {
 UINT8 j, i;
 static UINT16 jump;
 for (j = 0; j< 10; j++)
 {
 jump = dsc_jump

 for
  (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
 if
 (
 ((jump & 0x50 != 0)
  )
 {
 jump  = dsc_jump
  }
  }

  }
```

`UINT8` is a type you need to define in fake headers, and pycparser would not care about the undefinedness of `dsc_jump`, but the other errors are real problems:

1. There's no semicolon after `dsc_jump`
2. The `if` condition has an unterminated `(`

etc.